# Custom cursor graphic via jQuery.css()

Tags: jquery, css

I've created a .png file I'd like to use as a custom cursor on a specific element with class "next".

I'm using this code to no avail. Anything I'm missing?

```
$('.next').hover
(
    function(e) 
    {
    //$(this).css('cursor','all-scroll'); //WORKS!
    $(this).css('cursor','url(img/right-pointer.png)');
    });
```

Comment: is the file location right? Is it possible you need /img/right-pointer.png?

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/customcursor

Comment: Dave, that was it. Once I hardcode the URL it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use the following CSS:

`.next:hover    { cursor:url(img/right-pointer.png); }`